# Split a cell values into new column names

Tags: sql, csv, d3.js

I have a csv table holding data on movies with these values :

```
MovieID|  MovieRating | MovieGenres
```

`1      |  7           | Action & Adventures`

`2      |  6.5         | War & Horror`

And in order to visualize it with D3, I would like to change the table so it would look like this:

```
MovieID|MovieRating| isAction|isAdventures| isWar |isHorror

1      | 7         | 1       |  1         |  0    | 0

2      | 6.5       | 0       |  0         |  1    | 1
```

What tools can I use rather than actual write a code to change the csv file?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Itay, welcome to SO. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic. Please see guideline here https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you know the values for the genres.  If so, use `case` to generate the flags:

```
select m.*
       (case when MovieGenres like '%Action%' then 1 else 0 end) as isAction,
       (case when MovieGenres like '%Adventure%' then 1 else 0 end) as isAdventure,
       . . .
from movies m;
```

Note:  This assumes that the genres are single words that don't "overlap".  As written above, "War Action" would be in both categories.  There are ways around this, but they depend a bit more on the database, which you haven't specified.